# Response with lowercase letters in serialization and deserialization Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

The response of a WS is a json with first capitalize letters. I'm trying to encapsulate the response in a new **MyResponse** obj having lowercase first letters.

I'm using Jackson.

At first I have my models:

```
public class Telephone {

    private String country;
    private String prefix;

    //getters and setters
}

public class Position {

    private String x;
    private String y;

    //getters and setters
}

public class Root  {
    @JsonProperty("Telephone")
    private List<Telephone> telephone;
    @JsonProperty("Position")
    private List<Position> position;

    //getters and setters
}

public class MyResponse {

    private final Root root;
    private final String now;

    public MyResponse(Root root, String now) {
        this.root = root;
        this.now = now;
    }

    //getters
}
```

As you can see above, I used **@JsonProperty** in my `Root` class because I want to map my response using a first lowercase letter.

Now I have my RestController:

```
@Controller
public class RestController {

    @GetMapping("/my-controller")
    ResponseEntity<String> myController() {

        //Simulating the request to my ws to get my json string
        String jsonString = "{\n" +
                "   \"Telephone\":[\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "         \"country\":\"ES\",\n" +
                "         \"prefix\":\"+34\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "         \"country\":\"FR\",\n" +
                "         \"prefix\":\"+33\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "         \"country\":\"EN\",\n" +
                "         \"prefix\":\"+44\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "   ],\n" +
                "   \"Position\":[\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "         \"x\":\"123.23\",\n" +
                "         \"y\":\"98.93\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "         \"x\":\"250.99\",\n" +
                "         \"y\":\"43.89\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "   ]\n" +
                "}";

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        Root root = null;
        try {
            root = om.readValue(jsonString, Root.class);
            MyResponse myResponse = new MyResponse(root, LocalDateTime.now().toString());
            String responseAsString = om.writeValueAsString(myResponse);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(responseAsString, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

As you can see in the snippet of code above, at the beginning I got the json string (in my real code calling the WS) and I deserialized it into a Java POJO using the `readValue` method:

```
root = om.readValue(jsonString, Root.class);
```

Then I created my MyResponse obj using the deserialized POJO:

```
MyResponse myResponse = new MyResponse(root, LocalDateTime.now().toString());
```

And at the end, I serialized myResponse obj to String using `om.writeValueAsString` and I returned it to my frontend:

```
String responseAsString = om.writeValueAsString(myResponse);
return new ResponseEntity<>(responseAsString, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Since MyResponse obj is serialized and deserialized both using my Root @JsonProperty (s)
I get:

```
{
   "root":{
      "Telephone":[
         {
            "country":"ES",
            "prefix":"+34"
         },
         {
            "country":"FR",
            "prefix":"+33"
         },
         {
            "country":"EN",
            "prefix":"+44"
         }
      ],
      "Position":[
         {
            "x":"123.23",
            "y":"98.93"
         },
         {
            "x":"250.99",
            "y":"43.89"
         }
      ]
   },
   "now":"2021-06-24T11:18:04.077612"
}
```

That is not what I am trying to do: I have capitalize letters in my response.
How can I solve this problem? Should I use two different classes for serialization and deserialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried what suggested by Felix. But it didn't work, I got the following error:

```
Conflicting/ambiguous property name definitions found multiple explicit names: but also implicit accessor
```

After a while I was able to solve my problem in this way:

```
public class Root  {

private List<Telephone> telephone;
private List<Position> position;

@JsonCreator
public Root(@JsonProperty("Telephone") List<Telephone> telephon, @JsonProperty("Position") List<Position> position) {
    this.telephon = telephon;
    this.position = position;
}

    //getters and setters

}
```

The annotation `@JsonCreator` is used in deserialization phase only.
When one deserializes Jackson uses the constructor annotated with `@JsonCreator`. In serialization phase Jackson uses the fields name to convert the obj into String.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your Jackson annotations on getters and setters as well to let them behave differently. Like this:

```
public class Root  {
    private List<Telephone> telephone;

    @JsonProperty("Telephone")
    private void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    @JsonProperty("telephone")
    private String getTelephone() {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }
}
```